# pip install always clones git repos even if package is already installed

Tags: git, version-control, pip

Is there a way for pip to check if the git specified package is already installed and skip git cloning altogether?

Documentation mentions that you can specify the version after the egg definition but that is only for the visual convenience of the user and is not used anywhere.

Comment: I'm also looking for the answer to this question.  Have you discovered the answer since you originally asked this question?

Comment: pip 8 will just check if the git repo is cached so it won't pull it again but my issue is to not use git at all if the package is already there.

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, the solution was to change the URL from the form:

```
git+https://example.com/project.git@v5.5#egg=project-5.5
```

to this (remove the final version number):

```
git+https://example.com/project.git@v5.5#egg=project
```

Once I did that, I could run the pip install command repeatedly, and it would only clone the repository the first time.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Look like it was working with pip's legacy resolver (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75501243/how-to-install-a-package-with-pip-from-vcs-url-only-if-not-already-installed) but now it just clone again everytime...

Answer (score 0):

From [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)' answer to [Caching remote repository for pip installs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158192/caching-remote-repository-for-pip-installs):

> You can cache the result of the pip install as a Python Wheel:
>
> ```
> pip wheel --wheel-dir=/tmp/wheelhouse git+https://example.com/project.git#egg=project
> ```
>
> This builds a wheel for the repository in /tmp/wheelhouse. You can
>   then re-use the wheelhouse for subsequent installs:
>
> ```
> pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=/tmp/wheelhouse project
> ```
>
> The wheels won't be updated from the repository however.

This works for pure python repositories. If the repository you need hooks into C libraries that it builds (say some kind of NumPy or TensorFlow extension), you can try

```
pip download -d /tmp/pip_packages git+https://example.com/project.git#egg=project
```

and then for install

```
pip install --find-links /tmp/pip_packages project
```

If that still doesn't work, a last resort might be

```
git clone --depth=1 https://example.com/project.git ./project
pip install -e project
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case another noob like me is facing this issue, the re-cloning and re-building of the package could also happen because the egg name in the URL is incorrect.

Spcifically, if your project is called `project_name`, pip will name the package (and the egg) as `project-name` replacing the underscores with hyphens during the build process. So, you may need to change the URL from

```
git+https://example.com/project_name.git#egg=project_name
```

to

```
git+https://example.com/project_name.git#egg=project-name
```

Looking at the output of `pip install ...` will tell you the package name that is being created and used.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions from @krypto07 and @Nathan Stocks do not work anymore (it relies on pip's legacy resolver), and the solution from @Blaine Rogers only applies to your own machine.

---

I wanted to have a solution that would work from the `setup.py` of my package.

Here is the `setup.py` before (will clone the `cyhunspell` repo everytime, even the right version is already installed) :

```
from setuptools import setup


requirements = ["cyhunspell @ git+https://github.com/MSeal/cython_hunspell.git@2.0.3"]

setup(
    name='whatever',
    version='1.0.0',
    python_requires='>=3.8',
    install_requires=requirements,
)
```

And this is what I changed it to :

```
from importlib.metadata import PackageNotFoundError, version
from setuptools import setup


requirements = []

try:
    if version("cyhunspell") < "2.0.3":
        raise ValueError("Wrong version")
except (PackageNotFoundError, ValueError):
    requirements.append("cyhunspell @ git+https://github.com/MSeal/cython_hunspell.git@2.0.3")

setup(
    name='whatever',
    version='1.0.0',
    python_requires='>=3.8',
    install_requires=requirements,
)
```

Basically, upon installation it checks if `cyhunspell` is already installed with the right version. Only if `cyhunspell` is not installed or with the wrong version, the requirements list is updated with the VCS link (which will clone + install the right version).

---

-> If your package is not detected in `setup.py` but correctly detected in the REPL, read this section.

Somehow, my solution was not working in some cases (cyhunspell was correctly installed and showing up in `pip show`, but inside `setup.py` it was not shown).

It seems it's because in `setup.py`, python doesn't have access to the current environment (and all the installed packages...).

Here is my modified `setup.py` to make it work :

```
import os
import sys
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
from importlib.metadata import PackageNotFoundError, version
from setuptools import setup


# Somehow the current virtual env is not used when running `pip install`, which
# makes it impossible to detect the version of external dependencies such as
# `cyhunspell` or `fleksyenginemodule`.
# So, make sure that the current virtual env is added to the path.
env_path = get_python_lib()
sys.path.append(env_path)

# For dependencies installed in development mode (`pip install -e .`), we need
# to search and parse `.egg-link` files
for f in os.listdir(env_path):
    if f.endswith(".egg-link"):
        with open(os.path.join(env_path, f), "r") as f:
            egg_path = f.read().strip()
        egg_path = egg_path.split()[0]
        sys.path.append(egg_path)


requirements = []

try:
    if version("cyhunspell") < "2.0.3":
        raise ValueError("Wrong version")
except (PackageNotFoundError, ValueError):
    requirements.append("cyhunspell @ git+https://github.com/MSeal/cython_hunspell.git@2.0.3")

setup(
    name='whatever',
    version='1.0.0',
    python_requires='>=3.8',
    install_requires=requirements,
)
```

Basically it adds the current environment in the path, to make sure `cyhunspell` is correctly detected. It also adds any `.egg-link` paths, for dependencies installed in development mode.