# Avoid git clone while pip install from a private repo in requirements file

Tags: python, git, pip

`requirements.txt` file format:

```
package1
package2
git+https://github.com/dummy-org/dummy-repo.git@v1.0
```

I created a zip (`dummy-repo-1.0.zip`) of the private repo package using:

`pip download git+https://github.com/dummy-org/dummy-repo.git@v1.0`

And I am able to install the package via `pip install dummy-repo-1.0.zip`

When I try to install all the packages using `pip install -r requirements.txt`, every time it tries to clone the private repo. I want to skip this step.

Is it possible to avoid this cloning and use offline bundle or already installed package (from pip cache) for private repos?

Comment: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34788886/3279716) but I think it still will attempt to clone. The only (hacky) way I can think around this is filtering the repo from the file before calling `pip install`?

Comment: Aside from installing a proxy that keeps track of this for you, how do you expect pip to know that you already have a copy of some random web-site's zip file? (OK, GitHub isn't exactly *random* ... but isn't under your own control either, so...)

Comment: Pip should check cache before installing a package from github or  any other VCS. VCS suffix like `#egg=project-name==1.0` should be allowed which will indicate that I want to install 1.0 and if it's already there, skip the cloning.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked when I changed the requirements.txt, and replaced the URL with the path to the. Zip file. But this was a lang time ago, I am not Sure if it still works...

Comment: In my case, I can't use local path for this package in the first place.