# How to install a package with pip from VCS URL only if not already installed?

Tags: python, pip

With pip’s legacy resolver, it was possible to install a package from a VCS URL only if it is not already installed:

```
% pip install 'git+https://test.invalid/#egg=pip' --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
Requirement already satisfied: pip from git+https://test.invalid/#egg=pip in ./.virtualenvs/test_vcs_install/lib/python3.10/site-packages (23.0.1)
```

However, that doesn’t work with the new resolver:

```
% pip install 'git+https://test.invalid/#egg=pip'
Collecting pip
  Cloning https://test.invalid/ to /tmp/pip-install-bocqltdk/pip_cb75496a41934db7b07abef3e91b78ab
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://test.invalid/ /tmp/pip-install-bocqltdk/pip_cb75496a41934db7b07abef3e91b78ab
  fatal: unable to access 'https://test.invalid/': Could not resolve host: test.invalid
```

Is there a way to skip installation from a VCS URL if the package is already installed that works with the new resolver (and preferably the legacy resolver, too)?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788886/pip-install-always-clones-git-repos-even-if-package-is-already-installed