# Install requirement with pip from VCS, but not in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, pip

I have two Python packages in separate private repositories:

- app
- lib

App has a dependency on lib so in `app/pyproject.toml` I specify:

```ini
"lib @ git+ssh://git@github.com/user/lib.git#subdirectory=lib",
```

Each repository also has a Dockerfile with `app/Dockerfile` inheriting from `lib/Dockerfile`, i.e. `app/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM lib
```

`lib/Dockerfile` installs the lib package, but when I run `pip install -e .` in `app/Dockerfile`, it tries to reinstall lib from the git repo.

My current solution is to add `--use-deprecated=legacy-resolver` to the pip install as recommended in [How to install a package with pip from VCS URL only if not already installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75501243/how-to-install-a-package-with-pip-from-vcs-url-only-if-not-already-installed), however this is not optimal as I imagine the legacy-resolver will be removed from a future pip release. I also believe this must be a common issue when using Docker containers across multiple repositories so I don't believe this a duplicate of the referenced question.

I see there is a lot of discussion in the pip community, specifically https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10614, but I cannot see an ideal solution.